# Use MediaPicker outside Admin

Tags: file-upload, orchardcms, media, orchardcms-1.6

Crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/455072

I'm using Orchard 1.6.1

I know we can implement a mediapicker for editor templates of our custom modules/parts as detailed in this post: http://www.locked.nl/using-the-mediapicker-in-your-own-orchard-module

However, I'm wondering if we can use the media picker in the front-end for custom pages/forms with our own controllers. I want users to be able to upload images and such. Can we use the MediaPicker? Or do we have to implement one ourselves and use Media Services?

Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The media library picker is not designed to be used on the front-end. You will have to build your own.